# Vuforia 2 or more vumarks in the scene error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Problem is when the Uniyt package file with vumarks contain more then one vumark it shows error in the scene. If we separate vumark in different database, it helps to prevent this error but i need to have 9 different vumarks on the scene, and we cant create more than one Vumark object

```
Exception in callback: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Vuforia.VuMarkTrackableSimulationPool.IterateThroughTrackables (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] trackables, System.Int32& index, Vuforia.TrackerData+VuMarkTargetResultData[]& resultDataArray) [0x00061] in <ef8d686d707a43ad9c18ca2400443c5d>:0 
  at Vuforia.VuMarkTrackableSimulationPool.CreateTrackableArray () [0x00035] in <ef8d686d707a43ad9c18ca2400443c5d>:0 
  at Vuforia.VuMarkTrackableSimulationPool.CreateNativeDataArrays (Vuforia.TrackerData+VuMarkTargetResultData[]& activeVumarkArray, Vuforia.TrackerData+VuMarkTargetData[]& newVumarkDataArray) [0x00000] in <ef8d686d707a43ad9c18ca2400443c5d>:0 
  at Vuforia.VuforiaRuntimeTrackingSimulator.CreateNewManageFrameState () [0x00007] in <ef8d686d707a43ad9c18ca2400443c5d>:0 
  at Vuforia.VuforiaManager.Update (Vuforia.VuforiaScreenOrientation counterRotation, System.Boolean& reapplyOldState) [0x0001d] in <ef8d686d707a43ad9c18ca2400443c5d>:0 
  at Vuforia.VuforiaARController.UpdateStatePrivate (System.Boolean forceUpdate, System.Boolean reapplyOldState) [0x00051] in <ef8d686d707a43ad9c18ca2400443c5d>:0 
  at Vuforia.VuforiaARController.UpdateState (System.Boolean forceUpdate, System.Boolean reapplyOldState) [0x0000c] in <ef8d686d707a43ad9c18ca2400443c5d>:0 
  at Vuforia.DigitalEyewearARController.Update () [0x00000] in <ef8d686d707a43ad9c18ca2400443c5d>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in <8f06425e63004caf99a79845675f751e>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00083] in <8f06425e63004caf99a79845675f751e>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <8f06425e63004caf99a79845675f751e>:0 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x000e7] in <8f06425e63004caf99a79845675f751e>:0 
  at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00008] in <8f06425e63004caf99a79845675f751e>:0 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <8f06425e63004caf99a79845675f751e>:0 
  at Vuforia.DelegateHelper.InvokeDelegate (System.Delegate action, System.Object[] args) [0x0000f] in <ef8d686d707a43ad9c18ca2400443c5d>:0 
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Vuforia.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate (System.Delegate,object[])
Vuforia.DelegateHelper:InvokeWithExceptionHandling (System.Action)
Vuforia.VuforiaBehaviour:Update ()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Nope, it don't(

Comment: well theres no way we can answer your question. its just an error message. You need to work out what it says is null and fix it